# How to add onClick event on antd message?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have following question and I hope you can help me.

I have this code:

```
 const [msgTimer, setMsgTimer] = useState(5);

 message.error('some error msg', msgTimer);
```

In antd documentation `message` has `onClick` property. So how can I add that onClick event to my message?

I tried following but it not working.

```
 message.error('some error msg', msgTimer, onClick={()=>setMsgTimer(0)});
```

With that onClick I want immediately close that message.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to achieve is possible, but you'll need to use a different syntax, that allows you to set a **key** for a message.

```
const messageKey = 'some unique message key';
message.error({
  content: 'some error msg',
  duration: 5,
  key: messageKey,
  onClick: () => message.destroy(messageKey)
});
```

This way, you'll assign a unique **key** to the message, that you can later use in your **onClick** handler to remove that message.

Comment: hey the third argument is actually `onClose` and not `onClick` which the user wants

Comment: You're right, I'll update the answer